# Vaadin: "Ids must exist in the Container", after calling setVisibleColumns()

Tags: java, vaadin

I'm building small application based on SimpleAddressBook from Vaadin Tutorial.

Like in the tutorial I have a container extending BeanItemContainer which is used to populate a table.

Why I am getting:

```
       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Ids must exist in the Container or as a generated column , missing id: title
```

despite the fact that I have a 'title' field in my bean class?

BeanItemContainer:

```
package com.example.library.content;

import java.io.Serializable;
import com.vaadin.data.util.BeanItemContainer;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class BooksContainer extends BeanItemContainer<Book> implements
        Serializable {

    public static final Object[] NATURAL_COL_ORDER = new Object[] {
            "title", "author", "year", "ISBN"};

    public static final String[] COL_HEADERS_POLISH = new String[] {
            "Tytul", "Autor", "Rok", "ISBN"};

    public BooksContainer() throws InstantiationException,
            IllegalAccessException {
        super(Book.class);
    }

    public static BooksContainer createWithTestData() {
        final String[] titles = { "Peter", "Alice", "Joshua", "Mike", "Olivia"};
        final String[] authors = { "Smith", "Gordon", "Simpson", "Brown",
                "Clavel"};
        final int[] years = { 1594, 1834, 1922, 1983, 1984};
        final String isbns[] = { "4215 Blandit Av.", "452-8121 Sem Ave",
                "279-4475 Tellus Road", "4062 Libero. Av.", "7081 Pede. Ave",};

        BooksContainer booksContainer = null;
        try {
            booksContainer = new BooksContainer();

            for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
                Book book = new Book();
                book.setTitle(titles[i]);
                book.setAuthor(authors[i]);
                book.setYear(years[i]);
                book.setISBN(isbns[i]);

                booksContainer.addItem(book);
            }
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return booksContainer;
    }

}
```

Book:

```
package com.example.library.content;

public class Book {
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private int year;
    private String ISBN;


    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public String getISBN() {
        return ISBN;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public void setISBN(String isbn) {
        this.ISBN = isbn;
    }


}
```

BooksTableView

```
public class BooksTableView extends Table {

  public BooksTableView(LibraryApplication libraryApp) {
     setSizeFull();

     setContainerDataSource(BooksContainer.createWithTestData());

     setVisibleColumns(BooksContainer.NATURAL_COL_ORDER);
     setColumnHeaders(BooksContainer.COL_HEADERS_POLISH);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes hot deployment does not work correctly. Try stopping/undeploying your application, build it from scratch and restart/redeploy the application. It should work then.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same frustrating issue, did you manage to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code with Vaadin 6.8.2 and it works.